# Throw Exception when I compile module-info.java

Tags: java, exception, modular

I got the blow Exception when running with jar -cvf to create jar file from class.Does anyone expreience this similar problem when creating package file? Appreciate in advance.

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/folders/ms/zplmyl_j3y528bm2hb5sg3f40000gn/T/zoo.tours.api.jar15685611641399685111.jar -> ./mods/zoo.tours.api.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:476)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:266)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1426)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.validateAndClose(Main.java:438)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:321)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1649)
```

Comment: ./module-info.java:3: error: module not found: zoo.tours.api
    requires zoo.tours.api;
                      ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is I defined a path which is not created /mods, but I utilized this path to generate the jar package. To solve this problem, just remove the path and set the jar directly. Or try to create specific path firstly.

Answer (score 0):

The command is used for compile the class and java into jar package with existing custom module, the compile error will not throw exception with --module-path information on dependencies.

```
javac -g -d serviceLocatorModule --module-path zoo.tours.api.jar serviceLocatorModule/zoo/tours/reservations/*.java serviceLocatorModule/module-info.java
```

The problem refer to the OCP java11 complete guide for Modular Application.